# how to read data from input array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I want to read the values from  array amtrefunded[] in javascript. how to do it?

```
   <input type="number" name="amtrefunded[]"/>
```

Comment: Have you wrongly taken 'name' instead of 'value' ?

Comment: did you try something? show us

Comment: thanks for response, document.getElementsByName("amtrefunded[]") did the job

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName("amtrefunded[]")` will return a nodelist that you can iterate over.

Comment: thanks,got it document.getElementsByName("amtrefunded[]") did the job